# Import another module's repository in my module in nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to build an application with Nestjs and currently I have two modules: User and Auth with following structure:

[image]

I needed to inject **UsersService** into **AuthService** in order to interact with **User** entity, so first I've injected **UsersRepository** into **UsersService** and exported the service:

users.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository]),
  ],
  providers: [
    UsersService,
    UserRepository,
  ],
  exports: [
    UsersService,
    TypeOrmModule,
  ],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

users.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthCredentialsDto } from '../auth/dto/auth-credentials.dto';
import { JwtPayload } from '../auth/jwt-payload.interface';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}

  async signUp(authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto): Promise<void> {
    return this.userRepository.signUp(authCredentialsDto);
  }

  async validateUserPassword(authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto): Promise<string> {
    return this.userRepository.validateUserPassword(authCredentialsDto);
  }

  async findOne({ username }: JwtPayload): Promise<User> {
    return this.userRepository.findOne({ username });
  }
}
```

users.repository.ts:

```
import { ConflictException, Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { Repository, EntityRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { AuthCredentialsDto } from '../auth/dto/auth-credentials.dto';

@Injectable()
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  async signUp(authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto): Promise<void> {
    const { username, password } = authCredentialsDto;

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const user = new User();
    user.username = username;
    user.password = await this.hashPassword(password, salt);
    user.salt = salt;

    try {
      await user.save();
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === '23505') {
        throw new ConflictException('Username already exists');
      } else {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException();
      }
    }
  }

  async validateUserPassword(authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto): Promise<string> {
    const { username, password } = authCredentialsDto;
    const user = await this.manager.findOne(User, { username });

    if (user && await user.validatePassword(password)) {
      return user.username;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private async hashPassword(password: string, salt: string): Promise<string> {
    return bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
  }
}
```

Issue is when I need to call a **UserService** methods from **AuthService**, I'll get error with following format:

```
[Nest] 6267   - 11/08/2019, 3:30:52 AM   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined +4600ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
    at UserRepository.validateUserPassword (/home/firiz/Projects/giftos/api/dist/users/user.repository.js:35:41)
    at UsersService.validateUserPassword (/home/firiz/Projects/giftos/api/dist/users/users.service.js:26:36)
    at AuthService.signIn (/home/firiz/Projects/giftos/api/dist/auth/auth.service.js:24:49)
    at AuthController.signIn (/home/firiz/Projects/giftos/api/dist/auth/auth.controller.js:26:33)
    at /home/firiz/Projects/giftos/api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:37:29
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

My question is... what I'm missing, causing this painful issue!

Comment: Please post the code of your `auth.module.ts` file

Comment: Seeing as you're extending Repository, couldn't you call `this.findOne()`?

Answer (score 14):

You don't export & import the repository, you "recreate" the repository multiple times. In the module you want to "recreate" the repo (ie. something.module.ts file), you should import the TypeOrmModule with the repo entity you want.

Example:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      ...
      MyEntity,
    ]),
    ...
```

... then in the Service of the Module:

```
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(MyEntity) private repo: Repository<MyEntity>,
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to use repository pattern in nestjs with typeorm:

- Using default repository of typeorm.
- Using your own custom repository.

First way:

- In your module file:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],  // Typeorm will register a repository for your user entity internally
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

And in service you just simply do:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
}
```

Second way, custom repository:

- Firstly, you need to register your custom repository into typeorm and keep in mind that your custom repository will be treated as a provider.

```
@Module({
 imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository])],  // Typeorm will register your custom repository and treat it as **a provider**
 providers: [UsersService],
 controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

- Declare your custom repo:

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
   createSth() {}
}
```

- Then you just need to inject it as a provider in your service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly userRepository: UserRepository) {}

  async create(dto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const entity = new User();

    entity.username = dto.username;
    entity.email = '';
    entity.password = dto.password;

    return this.userRepository.createSth(entity);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

When you create your custom repository extends Repository you should work with it directly so try:

```
const user = await this.findOne(User, { username });
```

You can find [more about custom repo and manager here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/custom-repository.md)

Comment: But this as well doesn't solve the problem. I am facing the same issue.